# Irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z $

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

When I read "*Contemporary Abstract Algebra*" by Joseph gallian, under the topic irreducible polynomials, his first example is the 
polynomial $$2x^2+4=0$$ is reducible over $\mathbb  Z$ but irreducible over
$ \mathbb Q$. I dont know how is this possible? Since it is of degree 2, we can see the roots of the polynomial, where it lies? if it lies in $\mathbb Z$ then it would lie in $ \mathbb Q$, then how can it be reducible over $\mathbb Z$ when the roots are complex numbers? pls explain

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not the roots, it's the "$2$"!

A polynomial is irreducible over a ring if it cannot be written as a product of two non-invertible polynomials. In $\mathbb{Z}$, "$2$" is noninvertible, so $(x^2+2)2$ is an appropriately "nontrivial" factorization.

Meanwhile, over in $\mathbb{Q}$, the polynomial "$2$" is invertible, since ${1\over 2}$ is rational (proof: exercise :P). So the factoriztion $(x^2+2)2$ is "trivial" in the context of $\mathbb{Q}$, since we can *always* extract a factor of $2$ from any polynomial.

EDIT: Think of it this way: saying that a polynomial is irreducible over a ring means it has no "nontrivial" factorizations. Now, when we make the ring bigger (e.g. pass from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$) two things happen:

- More factorizations become possible.
- More factorizations become *trivial*.

So even though your first instinct might be "polynomials will only go from "irreducible" to "reducible" as the ring gets bigger," actually the opposite can happen!

In fact, here's a good exercise:

> Can you find a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ but reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

---

Note that the definition of reducibility over a *field* may sound different:

> For $F$ a field, a polynomial $p\in F[x]$ is *irreducible* if $p$ cannot be written as the product of two nonconstant polynomials.

But this is actually equivalent to the definition I gave above, in case we're over a field: the noninvertible elements of $F[x]$ are *precisely* the nonconstant polynomials!

Comment: Great explanation....But the exercise you gave "is there a polynomial like that?"? Because there is a theorem "if a polynomial is reducible over Q then it is reducible over Z" and i want to ask you a doubt..what happens to the theorem saying "if the degree of polynomials is of 2 or 3 then it is reducible over F[x] iff it has roots in F."

Comment: @SamChristopher Re: the first theorem you mention: Well, that sounds like that kills the exercise, doesn't it? There's a reason I phrased it the way I did :). (EDIT: Now, a parallel good exercise: find rings $R\subset S$ and a polynomial $p\in R[x]$ such that $p$ is reducible over $R$ but irreducible over $S$! There's something special about $\mathbb{Z}$ . . .) Re: the second theorem you mentioned: there you're taking $F$ to be a *field*. The theorem breaks down if $F$ is merely a *ring* like $\mathbb{Z}$ - look at the proof to see why.

Comment: Great.....Thank you...

Comment: The precise relationship between the two types of irreducibility (over Z and over Q) is solved by Gauss' lemma. More generally, let A be an UFD and K its field of factions. The irreducible elements of A[X] are either irreducible elements of A , or polynomials in A[X] which are irreducible in K[X] and have content 1. For a proof and the definition of "content", see e.g. the chapter on "Polynomials" in Lang's "Algebra"